# Modify mongodb cursor to add key of id and a given value

Tags: php, mongodb, algolia

I have this collection called rooms and i am querying it like this

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");


$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->rooms;

/**
$cursor = $collection->find();
$id = '609d3999c4f94943dc2f9233';
$item = $collection->findOne(["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id)]);
*/
$cursor = $collection->find();
```

I would like to fetch the existing document id and use that id to insert a key of `id` and a value being the id of the document i looped

```
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    
    echo (string)$document["_id"].'<br/>';
    /**
    $key = (string)$document["_id"];
    $data["$key"] = $document["property_name"];
    */
}
```

The above code outputs the id of the document.Since the cursor is iterable, i am doing this to convert it to json and sending it to Algolia.

```
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

However, i need a key called id to be able to set the objectid as algoloia only accepts a string for object id i.e

```
$index->saveObjects($data, ['objectIDKey' => 'id']);
```

How can i insert a key id with the value `(string)$document["_id"]` to the object i get from the cursor and encode it with the new key value that i inserted?.

Answer (score 0):

I added my own object id key when inserting data into my mongo collection. Its a concat of uniqud and timestamp so this should work for the time being

When saving data

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP object 
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->rooms;

$data['pk'] = uniqid().time();
$collection->insertOne($data);
```

to add to algolia

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->rooms;

$cursor = $collection->find();

$ao = iterator_to_array($cursor);

$client = Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient::create(
  '8****',
  '1***'
);

$index = $client->initIndex('hotel');

$index->saveObjects($ao, ['objectIDKey' => 'pk']);
```